# Can't resolve NotificationChannel's isBlockable() method even though it is explicitly mentioned in the docs

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Currently writing a flutter plugin, I want to know if a channel is blocked or is blockable, there is a public method that does that but I can't seem to access it.

the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#isBlockable()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your `compileSdkVersion` is set to `32` or lower. Raise it to `33` or higher, as that method is new to API Level 33.